# Invariant Violation in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native.
When I go to run project on Android emulator this error displayed.
I tried many solutions but didn't work.

Error log:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>       expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function 
>       (for composite components) but got: undefined.

LoginForm.js codes:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Button,Card,CardSection} from './components'

 class LoginForm extends Component{

    render(){

        return(
           <Card>

               <CardSection>
                   <Button>
                       Log in
                   </Button>
               </CardSection>

           </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

App.js codes:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Header} from './components';
import LoginForm from './components';

 class App extends Component{



    render(){

        return(

            <View>
                <Header headertext="Test"/>
                <LoginForm />
                </View>


        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('second', () => App);
```

components/index.js

```
export * from './Button';
export * from './Card';
export * from './CardSection';
export * from './Header';
```

[image: Project files]

Comment: Can you add the code for `index.js`

Comment: @PritishVaidya Sure, updated.

Comment: Sorry ,I mean , `components/index.js`

Answer (score 1):

In your components/index.js, you are exporting everything except LoginForm.js

So, when you're importing LoginForm from "./components" in App.js, it looks in the index.js file and doesn't find a default export.

You can add `export * from "./LoginForm"` in your `components/index.js` and import it as a named import in App.js, such as: `import {LoginForm} from "./components"`.

Or maybe you could `import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm"` directly.

Comment: This error comes after change: The development server returned response error code 500

Comment: are you making any connection to a server? if yes, then what? the problem can be from there

Comment: @BaderYS      I am using FireBase , Does  can it make problem?